# Can I run a Terraria server on one computer but play from another on the same Steam account?

Tags: terraria

I have a desktop computer where I have a copy of Terraria server running a world.  Normally I just play from there and join to my own IP address.  Sometimes I would like to play from my laptop and join into the server running on the desktop. However, every time I have tried I get a warning that I'm already playing Terraria on another computer and it will shut down that system in order to play on the current computer.  It then attempts to shut down the other computer's steam login, but never succeeds.

Is there any way to accomplish this?  Namely, have one computer act as server but connect to the server via another computer, while both are using the same Steam account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. In order to do this, you have to launch the dedicated Terraria server from the game folder.

1. Right click on Terraria in Steam and click Properties
2. Click on the `Local Files` tab and click on the `Browse Local Files...` button
3. Launch `TerrariaServer.exe` and follow instructions
4. Once the server is started, find out the local IP of your desktop PC (most likely looks something like 192.168.x.x)
5. On your laptop run Terraria and choose `Multiplayer -> Join via IP` and input the desktop PC's IP

If you followed everything right, it should connect to the server and you should spawn in your desktop server world.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I'm already doing.  I guess I wasn't explicit enough in my question, but I am running TerrariaServer.exe on the desktop.  The problem is that when I try to connect from a different computer logged in through the same account, it says I'm already playing Terraria because of the server.  I even tried starting the server then logging out of my steam account on the desktop, but then the server can't be contacted by any other computer.

Comment: Steam shouldn't care if the server is running or not, are you sure you don't have the game itself running on the desktop as well? I'll have to have a look at the server settings again...

Comment: @techturtle do you **own** Terraria or are you family sharing with someone else? And do you use the same account on your laptop as you do on desktop?

Comment: I just ran the server on my desktop and connected to it on wife's desktop with the same steam account. The instructions in my answer are correct, there must be something you're doing different.

Comment: I tried again last night by logging out of Steam on the desktop first and then starting the server, and that way worked.  I don't know what would be different about my setup (I do own it, no sharing going on) but for whatever reason if I was logged into steam at both computers, it wouldn't let my play on the laptop while the desktop ran the server.  If you will update your answer to include possibly needing to logout first, I will accept it.

Comment: Logging out shouldn't be required though, as the server doesn't require steam and shouldn't trigger steam drm like the game does. After you logged out, have you tried logging back in and then starting the server again? Have you restarted your desktop since you last played Terraria? Perhaps it never closed properly and it remained in your processes, thus keeping Steam thinking that you're still playing it. Logging out would fix it, if that was what was happening...

Comment: A couple of reboots later, and it appears to be working as you indicate (as such, I have accepted your answer).  Something hinky must have been going on with my copy, but it's no longer happening.